# Spark 3.0 -> Delta Lake 0.7.0 <-> AWS Glue Catalog -> Athena - implementing integration

Tags: pyspark, amazon-athena, delta-lake, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am using a stand-alone spark (pyspark) 3.0 with delta 0.7.0 on an EC2 instance.
Can someone direct me to a guide of how to migrate to Glue Catalog from Hive Metastore catalog (on derby).

If it makes sense, the goal is to have Spark jobs using the same catalog as Athena in an automated way.
Meaning, when schema change / new partition / new table / alter table happens on the Delta Catalog level it should be propagated to the Glue Catalog

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/tree/master/utilities/Hive_metastore_migration

Comment: This definitely makes sense, but might be easier to use an EMR 6.1.0 which comes with Spark 3.0 and install delta lake on top of it. There is a guide how to use [Glue Catalog on EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-glue.html).

Comment: thank you for your commen @Philipp-johannis,i would like to continue with the current setup. The EC2 instance is serving additional processes and deploying an additional EMR is not in my budget

Comment: @PrabhakrReddy, what you've suggested is migrating from Hive Metastore to Glue Catalog, but it is still not answers the requirement on how to connect the same catalog to both Spark Delta (write/read) and Athena (read)